# How to pass parameters to this SOAP function in PHP?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, php-7.4

I have a SOAP endpoint, so i get the functions with `$client->__getFunctions()` an i get this.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(143) "ResEds_ GETcotpaq_(string $sCid_, string $sCte_, string $sCor_, string $sCds_, string $xRec_, string $xEnt_, decimal $xVld_, EstCga_ $sDatDet_)"
  [1]=>
  string(61) "decimal CalcListaPrcFpl(decimal $Ps_, decimal $Vl_, int $Ln_)"
  [2]=>
  string(55) "decimal CalcListaPrcMult(string $xKgs_, decimal $xMts_)"
}
```

So i'm interested in the `GETcotpaq_` function, so i'm trying to pass the parameters described in the SOAP function.

```
$params = [
    'sCid_' => 'FA',
    'sCor_' => '44250',
    'sCds_' => '37000',
    'xRec_' => 0,
    'xEnt_' => 0,
    'xVld_' => 100,
    'sDatDet_' => [
         'xCntEmp_' => 1,
         'xPesUni_' => 10,
         'xVolUni_' => 10
    ]
];

var_dump($client->GETcotpaq_($params));
```

But I get this error `Message:  Array to string conversion`. How I should pass the parameters?